# How to install all relevant packages?

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js project which has several dependencies.

I created the package.json file (`npm init`) 
and try to install all the relevant packages

(`npm install all`) or (`npm install`)

with `npm install` I'm getting the following result:

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
```

but
when I'm trying to run, I'm getting error that a package is missing (i.e `express` and I need to install it manually)

Is there a way (command) to install at once (with one command) all the relevant packages and dependencies ? (instead of install each of the package manually) ?

Comment: just `npm install` will install all modules listed as dependencies in your `package.json` file.

Comment: dude initially you have to add dependencies one by one, into your package.json. Later on you can do `npm install` to install all of the ones you did manually before. PS i'd recommend making a shell script / boilerplate, so you can get a starting point.

Comment: add that to your version control

Answer (score 0):

### Update 1:

I think I found the solution to your problem, you can use [this npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-install) module for auto installing your dependencies.

[image: infographic gif]

Install
`npm install -g auto-install`

Usage
Run `auto-install` in the directory you are working in.

### So npm is simple!

you can add a single package using `npm install package-name`

or

you can install all using `npm install`, this will read your package.json file and install all the packages which are in there

Additionally you can do this:

`npm install package1 package2 package` to install multiple packages.

Comment: I updated the Q. I have trying with npm install but same results

Comment: @user3668129 and I added a comment on the post, which you should check.

Comment:  You do not need to install a global dependency just to help you install your dependencies.

Comment: @guyot dude I know that, but he doesn't want that. he wants something that automatically install his dependencies as he codes.

Answer (score -1):

If a required dependency is not installed, just install it once manually using npm's `--save` argument and it will automatically add that dependency to your package.json.

For instance, if you are missing the `express` dependency, just run:

`npm install --save express`

That will install the dependency in your node_modules folder and also automatically update your package.json file to include `express`. On subsequent installs on different machines, you'll now only need to run `npm install` and the `express` package will be added automatically.

---

Update with a little more context: In Node your package.json file defines all dependencies that are required for your project. However, these dependencies are *not* automatically generated for you. `npm init` will create a boilerplate package.json, but it will *not* fill that package.json with any dependencies.

You need to define the dependencies yourself, which you can do one of two ways:

1. Manually add lines to your package.json's `dependencies` section
2. Use `npm install --save <package name>` to have npm install a package and automatically save that package as a dependency in your package.json file

If you aren't familiar with package.json files, I'd recommend sticking to approach number 2 so that npm handles editing that file for you.

Once you have a package.json with all of the dependencies you need, then when you pull down your project onto new machines you will be able to automatically install all dependencies at once using a simple `npm install` command. You can test this on your own machine by deleting the node_modules folder and running `npm install`, then trying to run your project. If it runs fine then you successfully added all dependencies to your package.json. If it complains about a missing package then add that package with `npm install --save <package>`